# Error with using vector<data type> for compiling with arm

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am using vector< double > data type for a c++ program for TI CC3200 with energia but it is throwing a big error of

> waveletone\waveletnew.cpp.o: In function `std::_Vector_base<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_allocate(unsigned int) [clone .isra.41]':
>   waveletnew.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIdSaIdEE11_M_allocateEj.isra.41+0xa): undefined reference to`std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
>   waveletone\waveletnew.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::_M_check_len(unsigned int, char const*) const':
>   waveletnew.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIdSaIdEE12_M_check_lenEjPKc[_ZNKSt6vectorIdSaIdEE12_M_check_lenEjPKc]+0x18): undefined reference to`std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
>   waveletone\waveletnew.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >::_M_check_len(unsigned int, char const*) const':
>   waveletnew.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorISt7complexIdESaIS1_EE12_M_check_lenEjPKc[_ZNKSt6vectorISt7complexIdESaIS1_EE12_M_check_lenEjPKc]+0x18): undefined reference to`std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
>   waveletone\waveletnew.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::complex<double>*, std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > > >, std::complex<double> const&)':
>   waveletnew.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorISt7complexIdESaIS1_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EERKS1_[_ZNSt6vectorISt7complexIdESaIS1_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EERKS1_]+0x68): undefined reference to`std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
>   waveletone\waveletnew.cpp.o: In function `std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::complex<double>*, std::vector<std::complex<double>, std::allocator<std::complex<double> > > >, unsigned int, std::complex<double> const&)':
>   waveletnew.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorISt7complexIdESaIS1_EE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEjRKS1_[_ZNSt6vectorISt7complexIdESaIS1_EE14_M_fill_insertEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS1_S3_EEjRKS1_]+0xb0): undefined reference to`std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
>   waveletone\waveletnew.cpp.o: In function `iswt(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, int, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&)':
>   waveletnew.cpp:(.text._Z4iswtRSt6vectorIdSaIdEEiS2_+0x42c): undefined reference to`std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

waveletnew.cpp is the wavelet header source file.

Comment: These are linker errors, are you perhaps trying to link c++ code with a C (e.g. gcc) linker call.

Comment: are exceptions supported by your compiler options?

Comment: I am using energia and I do not have option to change compiler or any linker file change. any suggestions on how to change gcc to g++ ?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-fno-exceptions` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a linker error.

When you used functions in C++ STL, but didn't link the C++ libraries, maybe you can try to modify the `Application.mk` file and then add `APP_STL := gnustl_shared`. I hope that this will help you.